# Help to understand these two sentences from this article

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

I have some difficulty to understand the passive voice from these two sentences in [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/news/david-lynch-rebukes-trump-causing-suffering-division-191859676.html).

> On Monday, Trump tweeted a link to the Breitbart article that highlighted a comment Lynch made in a lengthy profile **published the Guardian**.

The part I am confusing is **published the Guardian**, which I think it should be **published by the Guardian** instead.

> All you need to do is treat all the people as you would like to **be treated**.

I'm wondering why the passive voice (**be treated**) should be used, instead of just **treat**. It seems logically incorrect to me.

Appreciate if someone can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regard to your first question, I suspect that it's just a misprint. Articles or profiles are usually published by someone or some organisation (such as a newspaper, for example). Here, the article they're talking about was published by the Guardian. So, there definitely needs to be a *by* between *published* and *the Guardian*. The following is how it should be written:

> On Monday, Trump tweeted a link to the Breitbart article that highlighted a comment Lynch made in a lengthy profile published **by** the Guardian.

In regard to your second question, think about it for a second. You try to treat people well and hopefully in return you expect them to treat you well too. The latter implies that you want to be treated by them well. So, how would you like to be treated by other people? I think you would like to be treated well because you yourself try to treat them well. That's why a passive voice is used there.